# A Trivial Pursuit #13 (Geography 3/4): Things Fall Apart

Tags: word, knowledge, wordplay, visual, geography

<sub>This is part 13 of [A Trivial Pursuit](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a60644%20is%3aq%20%22a%20trivial%20pursuit%22&searchOn=3), a 25-part puzzle hunt. Each part is solvable on its own, with the exception of the meta-puzzle at the end.</sub>

---

Identify the 26 words clued by the images below, then infer a hidden 'top-10 list' among them. One entry is missing - **what is it?**

[image: 26 clues]

Comment: Just confirming that the "O" is in the right spot in its word and that it's not supposed to be rot13(cbaf)

Comment: @samm82 I can confirm that it's in the right place. Thanks for checking though :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This puzzle is about...

> the most [populous settlements in East Sussex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_settlements_in_East_Sussex_by_population)

To start with, we note that the pictures represent the words

> **HILaL** (i.e. the Islamic crescent, shown here on the Maldivian flag) (thanks juicifer)
>  **bOUGH**
>  **cLEWES** ([Howard Clewes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Howard_Clewes), one of the screenwriters for *The Day They Robbed the Bank of England*)
>  **dEHAVEN** ([Gloria DeHaven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gloria_DeHaven), lead actress in *Summer Holiday* (1948))
>  **eTON** College
>  **AFfORD**
>  **gLADE**
>  **PEACh** (the background color is onbly for extraction purposes, [this](https://htmlcolorcodes.com/colors/peach/) is the actual color)
>  **URiNE**
>  [**BOj**](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4402132/)
>  **kEA** (as in Mauna Kea, the highest point in Hawaii)
>  **lEAST**
>  **SEAm**
>  **CROWn**
>  [**oBEX**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obex) (thanks juicifer)
>  [**HOp**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hop_(film))
>  **qAND** ([the Arabic word for rock candy](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D9%82%D9%86%D8%AF#Arabic))
>  **STrINGS** (seen here not attached to a guitar)
>  **sPORTS** (EA Sports)
>  **BRIGHt** ([Millie Bright](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millie_Bright), a member of the English women's national football team, aka the Lionesses)
>  **BuYS**
>  [**SEv**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sev_(food))
>  **wON**
>  **VEx**
>  **HAy** (as in [Hay-on-Wye](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hay-on-Wye), a town on the border between Wales and England)
>  **BORz** ([the Hungarian word for badger](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/borz#Hungarian))

We can then

> Patch together the capitalised letters according to the colour of their detailing in approximate spectral order:
>  BRIGH+TON+AND+HO+VE (whose pictures were augmented with RED detailing)
> EAST+BO+URNE (ORANGE detailing)
> HA+STINGS (YELLOW detailing)
> BEX+HILL+ON+SEA (LIME GREEN detailing)
> SE+AFORD (DARK GREEN detailing)
> CROW+BOR+OUGH (BLUE detailing)
> PORTS+LADE+BYS+EA (INDIGO detailing)
> PEAC+EHAVEN (VIOLET detailing)
> and um LEWES (MAGENTA detailing)

the solutions for

> LEWES, HASTINGS and SEAFORD were easy to identify and satisfied a natural link.

which leaves

> HAILSHAM. (A quick Google on top ten East Sussex towns leads to the wikipedia page quoted at the beginning and Hailsham is the missing entry).

Comment: a is {uvyny} and o is {bork}

Comment: This is the correct final answer, but there are a few things missing to help someone follow your reasoning... (i) How did you decide _which ones_ to 'patch together'? (ii) Which one(s) did you recognise that made you realise you were patching them together correctly and this idea was worth pursuing? (iii) How does the final answer relate to the other things you find? (At the moment that logic is only presented indirectly in the Wikipedia link...) Thanks!

Comment: @Stiv I've added some elucidation; let me know if more is required. I also haven't worked out if there's some Yeats reference going on with the title or if it jsut references patching things together.

Comment: Great, much improved, thank you :) Funnily enough, I didn't realise the title was a quote from Yeats - I was thinking of the Chinua Achebe novel (whose title - I now learn - was in turn inspired by Yeats!). And I intended it merely as a reference to needing to reassemble some 'things' that had 'fallen apart' - it just seemed like the right fit...